# Incrementing a value with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a `mongoose` model in my `node.js` application, representing invoices. I have figured most of it out already, but I really need to ensure that my invoices are numerated/incremented to be able to provide a proper reference to my customer.

Using an SQL database, I would have created an `AUTO-INCREMENT` column holding this value, but this obviosly isn't built into MongoDB. So how would I accomplish this with `mongoose`?

Here's how my model looks right now:

```
var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    reference: {type: Number, default: 0}, // The property I want to auto-incr.

    dates: {
        created:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        expire: {type: Date, default: expiryDate()}
    },

    amount: {type: Number, default: 0}
    // And so on
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Generally in MongoDB, one does not use an auto-increment pattern for
>   _id's (or other fields), as this does not scale up well on large database clusters. Instead one typically uses Object IDs.

For more info checkout this link: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

So bottom line you can just use Object IDs, those are unique.

Answer (score 27):

```
Controller.findByIdAndUpdate(ID_HERE, {$inc: {next:1}}, function (err, data) {


});
```

// next is the field , type: Number

Comment: For the title of the question, this is the answer most people will be looking for.

Comment: If you need to increment a document field, you can use `your_doc.update({$inc: {next:1}})` directly. [Doc here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) what you looking for?

Let's say `UserSchema` and `InvoiceSchema` looks like this:

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    // other fields
    invoices: [{ type: Schema.Objectid, ref: 'Invoice' }]
});

var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    reference: { type: Schema.Objectid, ref: 'User' },

    dates: {
        created:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        expire: {type: Date, default: expiryDate()},
    },

    amount: {type: Number, default: 0}
    // And so on
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on keithic's answer:

You can add an additional object to make sure to receive the document AFTER it's been incremented, as such, I am using lean() and exec() to make sure the document is a plain Javascript object:

```
Controller.findByIdAndUpdate(ID_HERE, {$inc: {next:1}}, { $new: true})
   .lean().exec(function (err, data) {


});
```