# Mongoose won't increment number field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using MongoDB and Mongoose. I currently have a <kbd>like</kbd> button, and when I click it I would like to increment the 'likes' field in my document. Currently my document has the following schema:

```
brote {
  name: 
  content:
  created: 
  likes: 
}
```

and I have tested that the ID in my query matches that of the object in my database.

I consulted [How do I increment a Number value in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444213/how-do-i-increment-a-number-value-in-mongoose) and [Incrementing a value with mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987372/incrementing-a-value-with-mongoose) but these solutions did not seem to make any changes to my database. Perhaps there is something blatantly obvious that I am missing?

**Index.js**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bromies', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
var Brote = mongoose.model('Brote', broteFormSchema);

app.post('/likes', (req, res) => {
    let query = { id: req.body._id};
    Brote.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$inc: { 'likes': 1 }});

  })
```

Comment: Check the query object I think it should be {_id: req.body._id}. I will like to know the data type for the likes in your model

Comment: @QuajoDuke I changed id to _id and it still does not change the field :( The datatype is Number

Comment: Did you try doing this :: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function) ? I guess that should solve your issue, If not How does your `Brote` schema look like & also provide sample docs..

Comment: Did also try adding {new: true} option to the findOneAndUpdate. Or do this: 
`const brote = Brote.findById(query); Brote.UpdateOne(query, {$set: {'likes': brote.likes + 1}})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the `findOneAndUpdate` method does not work without a callback. Try passing a callback like this:

```js
    let query = { _id: req.body._id}; // It is _id, not id
    Brote.findOneAndUpdate(
        query, 
        {$inc:{ likes: 1}},
        (err, brote) => {    // callback
            console.log(brote);
        }
    )
```

**Edit:**
The reason it won't work is because it returns a Query if callback is not passed to it. You can call `.exec()` on the returned Query to execute it.

From the docs of [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate):

> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. **The query executes if callback is passed.**